# How to get the within-group variance-covariance matrix in statsmodels MANOVA, Python?

Tags: python, statsmodels, variance, covariance-matrix, manova

I am trying to extract the within-group variance-covariance matrix to estimate the flatness in a MANOVA model in statsmodels using the following formula: [image: flatness]

I've been reading through the statsmodels user guide, but haven't come across it.
What I have managed so far is this:

```
resid = manova.mv_test().results['x1']['E']
n * (xbar_tot).T @ np.linalg.solve(?, resid) @ xbar_tot
```

In R, the same can be accomplished by calling:

```
n * t(xbar.tot) %*% solve(summary(mod, test="Wilks")$SS$Residuals) %*% xbar.tot
```

What I am missing is the first part of the inverse, the where I have the `?` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the solution is simply the `E matrix`: so for the statsmodels manova question I asked, one proceeds as follows::

```
#1. run the statsmodel manova model
manova = MANOVA.from_formula('dv1 + dv2 ~ y', data=dy)

#2. extract the E matrix from the mv_test().results
resid = manova.mv_test().results['y']['E']

#3. obtain Hotelling's T^2
n * (xbar_tot).T @ np.linalg.solve(resid) @ xbar_tot
```

Comment: Is there a typo in the last line of the code? np.linalg.solve requires 2 arguments

Comment: Yes, there is a typo (thanks for catching it). It's supposed to be `linalg.inv`, not `linalg.solve`. So the full code should read  ```#1. run the statsmodel manova model
manova = MANOVA.from_formula('dv1 + dv2 ~ y', data=dy)

#2. extract the E matrix from the mv_test().results
resid = manova.mv_test().results['y']['E']

#3. obtain Hotelling's T^2
n * (xbar_tot).T @ np.linalg.inv(resid) @ xbar_tot```